# $.post showing in console.log() but no access to the variable on my php page

Tags: php, jquery

I'm pretty inexperienced with jquery. My code is

```
function edit(uID){ 
  var php = "body/weekly_deals.php";
  var data = {"edit" : "post is here"}
  $.post(php, data,function(response){
    console.log(response);
    });
 }
```

This is being defined on a WeeklyDeal.php. Now, on my body/weekly_deals.php page, I var_dump($_POST['edit']) and I'm getting NULL, however in the console.log, I'm seeing the value "post is here" string? So, I'm confused. How can it be there, but not be there at the same time?

Comment: `var_dump($_POST, $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])`. make sure there's no redirects or whatever, and see what IS arriving at the server.

Comment: put  ' ; ' after  var data = {"edit" : "post is here"}

Comment: @MarcB Hey, I did that, I got array(0){} String(3) "GET"     How is this so??

Comment: @stweb I get the same result with the semicolon

Comment: start debugging: figure out WHY your post got redirected.

Comment: try var data = {edit : "post is here"} instead of  var data = {"edit" : "post is here"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are misunderstanding how this works.

> I var_dump($_POST['edit']) and I'm getting NULL

The way you phrased your question, it sounds like you are not seeing that null in your `console.log()`, which is what *would* happen if you had the `var_dump` and called it with ajax. Instead, it sounds like you are loading **weekly_deals.php** directly in the browser and, since that is a GET request, not a POST request, and no parameters are being passed, it comes back empty.

> however in the console.log, I'm seeing the value "post is here" string

Right, because javascript is making an HTTP request using the POST method and passing a parameter.

---

I think you  may be confused about how an HTTP request works. To break it down, you have a resource which comes as a URI -- you know this as the web address. You can ask it questions in a few different ways -- GET, POST, PUT, etc. A web browser, when navigating to a page, issues a GET request to the resource. The web server returns the response and renders it.

When you make an AJAX request, you are doing something very similar as far as the request life cycle is concerned. When you make the request, the server renders the response and sends it back. That is why your `console.log()` has what you expect to see -- because AJAX made the request the server side expected to get. When you navigate to the page directly in the browser, it is the wrong type of request and thusly you see the wrong response.